# Why does a texture used on opengl objects looks poor in quality and stretched?

Tags: opengl, textures

Here is the [reference of library](http://www.chai3d.org/doc/classc_texture2_d.html) I am using

The texture when pasted over a opengl wall looks low in resolution and has poor quality, how can I improve it?

code

```
ground->m_texture = new cTexture2D();
fileload = ground->m_texture->loadFromFile(RESOURCE_PATH("resources/images/shadow.bmp"));
ground->setUseTexture(true);
ground->m_texture->setSphericalMappingEnabled(true);//this line is for circular objects, but without it texture doesnt even show up
```

from an example - how it should look

[image]

How it looks in my implementation[image]

Comment: What the...  They look very different....

Comment: does that model supply uv coordinates, so that OpenGL even knows where to put the texture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, what's happening is the following: Spherical mapping generates texture coordinates based on the vertex-to-viewport vector and the normal at the vertex to map it into a spherical reflection directions mapped into a sort-of fisheye image. Since your geometry looks like it's  quite flat, the variation of texture coordinates generated by this method will be rather small, which means, that you're largely magnifying your image. If now your texture filtering mode is set to nearest filtering, this is what will happen.

Solution: don't use spherical texture mapping. If you want to emulate a reflection, use cubemaps (they behave much better for small deviations in the reflection vector) and switch to linear filtering mode.